# Dropdown Menu not able to design in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DropdownMenu from './DropdownMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

    state = {
      topCategory: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data.express.catalogGroupView);
          this.setState({
            topCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
          })
        })
    }

  render() {

  const { topCategory } = this.state;
  const navList = topCategory.map(navList => {

    return (

        <DropdownMenu>
        <li key={navList.uniqueID}> <button onClick={this.showMenu}>{navList.name}</button></li>
        </DropdownMenu>
      )

  })

  return (
    <div>
    <ul className="header">{navList}</ul>
    </div>

  )

  }


  }

  export default Navigation;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';



class DropdownMenu extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showMenu: false,
    };

    this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
    this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
  }

  showMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showMenu: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }

  closeMenu() {
    this.setState({ showMenu: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }
  render() {

    return (
        <div>
        {
          this.state.showMenu
            ? (
              <div className="menu">
                <button> Menu item 1 </button>
                <button> Menu item 2 </button>
                <button> Menu item 3 </button>
              </div>
            )
            : (
              null
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropdownMenu;
```

I'm new to react and have created a navigation menu in react js. On clicking on the nav items a dropdown should appear. But in my case, it's not working, mainly the dropdown part.Can someone please guide me on this. I have tried numerous methods, but it seems not to be working. If someone could some help or atleast show me, I would be very much be grateful

Comment: what's not working? what exactly is your problem? Does it give you an error? I have some troubles understanding your code

Comment: Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
for more information.
    in DropdownMenu (at topNavigation.js:30)
    in Navigation (at Main.js:20)
    in div (at Main.js:17)
    in Main (at index.js:9)

It's showing error.....But the content is not rendering...It's just blank....Suppose If i have to create a dropdown then how would I proceed

Comment: I think you have to read better how props work and how to pass props to the children element, the code you have there it's not well organized i would say, unless i'm looking at it wrong

Comment: The li component is encapsulated under  <DropdownMenu> component and it's not rendering.....

Comment: Ok.So by reading about the Props it would solve my problem

Comment: it will definitely, i don't know if it will solve it

Comment: But if you have to implement how will you do it.Can you share some help.

Comment: to address the unique key error you may need to add an index to you're map like so > `navList = topCategory.map(navList, index =>` and the use the index in each `li` like so > `<li key={index}>`.

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya i would pass the show and close functions to a higher order component pass through props. I have trouble understanding some of the code you have there. i can refer you to material-ui framework they have dropdowns and you can see their example and make your mind

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of issues in your code.

1. In Navigation component I see the onClick is `this.showMenu` but there is no such function bound to that component.
2. You might need to read and understand how state and props work.

Hope the below snippet helps.

```js
class DropdownMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
    };   
  }

  
  render() {

    return (
        <div>
        {
          this.props.showMenu
            ? (
              <div className="menu">
                <button> Menu item 1 </button>
                <button> Menu item 2 </button>
                <button> Menu item 3 </button>
              </div>
            )
            : (
              null
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Navigation extends React.Component {

    state = {
      topCategory: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      topCategory: [{uniqueID:1000,name:'Nav Item 1'},{uniqueID:1001,name:'Nav Item 2'},{uniqueID:1002,name:'Nav Item 3'}]
    })
    }

  render() {

  const { topCategory } = this.state;
  const navList = topCategory.map(navListItem => {

    return (
            <li key={navListItem.uniqueID}> <button onClick={(e) => (this.setState({selected:e.target.innerText}))}>{navListItem.name}</button>
            <DropdownMenu showMenu={(()=>{
            
            return this.state.selected === navListItem.name})()}/></li>
      )

  })
  return (
    <div>
        <ul className="header">{navList}</ul>
    </div>

  )

  }


  }




ReactDOM.render(<Navigation />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```